# How to store an array of LinkedList heads in C++?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, binary-search-tree

Given a binary tree, I'm trying to make a linked list of elements for each depth. That makes D lists for depth D. I'm doing a non-recursive implementation and using level order traversal in my C++ code. Though I don't see any error while compilation, I know that my heads are not storing in the array of pointers. Please have a look at my code. Any help or suggestion would be great since I'm new to data structures. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

struct BTnode
{
    int data;
    BTnode* left;
    BTnode* right;
};

struct LLnode
{
    int data;
    LLnode* next;
};

BTnode* newNode(int data)
{
    BTnode* node = new BTnode;
    node->data = data;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    return node;
}

void MakeLL(LLnode* &head, int data)
{
    LLnode* temp = new LLnode;
    temp->data = data;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = temp;
        temp->next = NULL;
    }
   else
   {
       temp->next = head;
       head = temp; 
   }
}

LLnode** LevelElementsLinkedlist(BTnode* &root)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return NULL;

    queue<BTnode*>nodeQ;
    nodeQ.push(root);

    int level = 0;
    LLnode **arr;

    while(1)
    {
        int count = nodeQ.size();

        if (count == 0)
            break;

        LLnode* head = NULL;
        arr[level] = head;
        level ++;

        while (count > 0)
        {
            BTnode* node = nodeQ.front();

            MakeLL(head,node->data);

            nodeQ.pop();

            if (node->left)
                nodeQ.push(node->left);
            if (node->right)
                nodeQ.push(node->right);

            count--;
        }
    }

    return arr;
}

    void printLL(LLnode* head)
    {
       if (head == NULL)
       return;
       LLnode* temp = head;

       while (temp != NULL)
       {
         cout << temp->data << " ";
         temp = temp->next;
       }
     }

 int main()
 {
    BTnode* root = newNode(1);
    root->left        = newNode(2);
    root->right       = newNode(3);
    root->left->left  = newNode(40);
    root->left->right = newNode(5);
    root->right->left = newNode(60);
    root->right->right = newNode(7);
    root->left->left->left = newNode(8);
    root->left->left->right = newNode(9);
    root->left->right->left = newNode(10);
    root->left->right->right = newNode(11);
    root->right->left->left = newNode(12);
    root->right->left->right = newNode(13);
    root->right->right->left = newNode(14);
    root->right->right->right = newNode(15);

    LLnode** arr = LevelElementsLinkedlist(root);

    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    cout << n;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printLL(arr[i]);
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why not use vector of nodes?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problem that I noticed in your code.

In the function `LevelElementsLinkedlist`, you are not allocating space for `arr`. It should be `LLnode *arr = new LLnode *[100]`.

Check the line where you have written the following:

```
LLnode* head = NULL;
arr[level] = head;
```

You are assigning `NULL` to head and then adding it to the array. Your whole array will contain nothing else but NULLs.

Try fixing these issues and try executing your code again.

Comment: Thanks @Ankit for pointing out that I wasn't allocating memory while initializing the array. Since, I didn't want to pre allocate the number of elements the array will have; I changed my approach and instead made a list of lists. This works perfectly fine.